# Dynamically control Download by RTF option in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have enabled the "RTF" option present in the attributes section of the "Interactive Report" in APEX. Now, I am able to download the content of the interactive report into a RTF document, but I have to allow only certain type of users to access this download functionality.

I thought of making use of CSS to set the property of the RTF tag to "Hidden" based on the user accessing the page, I was wondering if there is a better approach to fulfill this requirement. I had a look at the authorization settings but it was not applicable for the Download option.

Lastly, I tried using the API "APEX_UTIL.DOWNLOAD_PRINT_DOCUMENT", but this approach requires the creation of Word template using BI publisher and uploading it to "Reports Layout" in the shared components, but this looks like an overkill.

Please advise, Thanks.

Comment: There are no authorization options for download options, unfortunately. The only way I can think of is to have two different Interactive Report regions; one has the option switched on, one switched off; and put conditions on each region so only one is rendered depending on the user's access.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with selecting columns, but I think this should work...

You can create a new button in the interactive report region (Download or something).

- The button can include the condition you want.
- *Position = Right of InteractiveReport .*
- Behavior Set to Redirect to URL: 
   javascript:$("#DetailReport1_actions_menu").menu("find","irDownload").action()

  - DetailReport1 = The Static ID of your IR.

Remove the Download option from the actions menu on the IR, but keep the RTF checked.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing this solution, but my current version is 5.1.3 and when I set the Download option to "No" in the IR the RTF option gets hidden.

If i continue with the approach then clicking on the new button opens up the download dialog but it does not have any options, the dialog is blank with just one statement "Choose report download format:".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking your time in answering this question. I got around it by making use of CSS to hide the tag with the below piece of code.

```
<style type="text/css">
a#REQUEST_IR_ADMIN_download_RTF {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

"REQUEST_IR_ADMIN" is the static ID that I provided to the region. All I have to do now is to create a new button and have the property as "redirect to URL" which redirects to the RTF download page "f?p=Application_ID:2:SessionID:RTF::::".

I will control the user access via this new button.